# Kotlin: Return can be lifted out of 'when'

Tags: kotlin

The alternative to `switch` in Kotlin is `when`.  So, inside a recycler view adapter, when I am returning view type, I use `when`:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    when (position) {
        0 -> return ItemViewType.TITLE.type
        1 -> return ItemViewType.SUBTITLE.type
        2 -> return ItemViewType.ITEM.type
        else -> return -1
    }
}
```

But, the above statement sends our warning message `Return can be lifted out of 'when'`.

Does anyone know what may be the correct way of using `when`? And what should be done to fix the above case?

Comment: just put return word before when keyword and try

Comment: @chandanicshekhat You'll still have to remove the `return` statements of the `when` block body to make use of that return

Comment: A general tip: put your mouse on the problematic code and hit Alt-Enter. AS should be able to fix warnings like that by itself

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You’re using `when` like a simple Java `switch` statement, which is okay but not very idiomatic and can be improved. You can refactor your code in two steps:

1. Kotlin's `when` can be used as an expression, it [returns a value if you wish](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html):

   ```
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> TITLE.type
            1 -> SUBTITLE.type
            2 -> ITEM.type
            else -> -1
         }
    }
   ```
2. The function body, now consisting of a single statement, can be changed into an [expression body](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions):

   ```
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = when (position) {
         0 -> TITLE.type
         1 -> SUBTITLE.type
         2 -> ITEM.type
         else -> -1
    }
   ```

Comment: Related: if statement can also be used as an expression: so you can return

if(a>b) a else b

Came to this answer getting the same warning message from an if statement

Comment: As a Kotlin beginner, this just strikes me as very elegant in comparison to Java

Comment: @Tom Welcome to Kotlin! You'll find that to be a common theme

Comment: Yes. It's interesting how Kotlin and ES6 Javascript resemble each other too

Comment: @s1m0nw1...I need to excute the same code but depend on two integer values example postion1 and postion2 ..please any help

Comment: @engmms have a look at the when expression examples in the documentation, I'm sure you will find something similar there? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression - you may have more advanced matching expressions that work on multiple inputs e.g. when { position1==0 && position2==1 -> ...} this is basically a replacement for an if/else chain

Comment: @s1m0nw1...thnx I solve it by use combination of two WHEN Statement

Answer (score 10):

Your `when` is correct, however Kotlin has the ability to lift the return out of the 'when' if you are returning in every case, thus it becomes :

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when (position) {
        0 -> ItemViewType.TITLE.type
        1 -> ItemViewType.SUBTITLE.type
        2 -> ItemViewType.ITEM.type
        else -> -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin, several statements, including `if`, `when` and `try`, can return a value. So in your case, you can refactor the statement to have the `when` statement return the actual value, which you can then return from the function.

So, you can simplify your method to the following:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = when (position) {
    0 -> ItemViewType.TITLE.type
    1 -> ItemViewType.SUBTITLE.type
    2 -> ItemViewType.ITEM.type
    else -> -1
}
```