# Kotlin: Why should 'return' be lifted out of 'if'? (Recommended by Android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The following code (simplified example):

```
/** Determine if a is less than 15 and b is more than 15. **/
fun isFifteenBetween(val a: Int, val b: Int) {
    if((a < 15) && (b > 15)) { return(true) }
    else { return(false) }
}
```

should make `isFifteenBetween(3, 20)` return **true**, and `isFifteenBetween(20, 3)` return **false**. However, I get the following recommendation from Android studio (v3.4):

```
Return should be lifted out of 'if'
Inspection info: This inspection reports if, when and try statements
that can be converted to expressions by lifting a return or an assignment out.
Typical example:

fun foo(arg: Boolean): String {
    when (arg) {
        true -> return "Truth"
        false -> return "Falsehood"
    }
}
```

The only related question I have found at stackoverflow is [Kotlin: Return can be lifted out of 'when'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018091/kotlin-return-can-be-lifted-out-of-when), but this doesn't quite seem to cover my case, I think.

1. How should my code be written? I don't understand how the 'when'-expression provided by Android studio is supposed to fit in my case.
2. Is the recommendation from Android studio simply a matter of taste and comfort, or will a change of code in this case actually make an impact on performance?
3. Are there any guidelines available for best practise?

Comment: OT: you could make `return a < 15 && b > 15` to simplify your function

Comment: I believe it is because you are checking a Boolean to return a Boolean.  Instead, you could just return the check for the Boolean:

`return ((15 - a) >= 1) && ((b - 15) >= 1)`

Comment: @crgarridos: I have updated the question. The code was simplified from a more complex piece of code, and I didn't catch that one. Thank you.

Comment: you could have used `fun isFifteenBetween(val a: Int, val b: Int) = a <15 && b > 15`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The official convention is to prefer to return the expression itself:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#using-conditional-statements

This said the example from android studio should become:

```
return when (arg) {
    true -> "Truth"
    false -> "Falsehood"
}
```

This will change the code of `isFifteenBetween` to:

```
/** Determine if a is less than 15 and b is more than 15. **/
fun isFifteenBetween(val a: Int, val b: Int) {
    return if((a < 15) && (b > 15)) true 
    else false
}
```

In terms of performance, both alternatives are almost equivalent.

---

These answers could be a little influenced by my opinion. but I think is more or less the reason behind. The fact of return the expression give direct impact while reading the piece of code. You know the result of the statement will be exhaustive and you have the information that every branch has been treated.

I consider this a best practice because in some case making a branching condition exhaustive could make the compiler give you an error while forgetting some new conditions. More than all for sealed classes. Further reading: https://proandroiddev.com/til-when-is-when-exhaustive-31d69f630a8b

Comment: I have accepted your answer, due to your explenation of exhaustive principles. I was not aware of this. In the end, however, I believe the expression suggested by @forpas, `return (a < 15) && (b > 15)`, is probably the most simple and readable solution. Hence, I will be using something similar in my code.

Answer (score 7):

The message is quite clear:

> This inspection reports if, when and try statements that can be
>   converted to expressions by lifting a return or an assignment out.

And it states the fact that:

> In Kotlin, if is an expression, i.e. it returns a value.

You can find more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression
In your case, you can return the result like this:

```
return if((a < 15) && (b > 15)) true else false
```

So this:

```
if((a < 15) && (b > 15)) true else false
```

is an expression and its value is returned by `return`.

This expression can be further simplified (but it's not related to your question):

```
return (a < 15) && (b > 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin *when* replace *switch-operator* from java, but main difference is that *when* is an **expression**, therefore it can return result. 
To better understand how does work when-expression in Kotlin, you can have a look on lambdas. The when-operator just returns result of its 'lambda' after each case.

Even if you write

```
when(a) {
    1 -> println("one")
    else -> println("something else")
}
```

---

This notation returns result of function println(...), that returns Unit. Therefore it isn't the best way to write code, when you duplicate this 'return'.

```
val result = when(a) {
    1 -> println("one")
    else -> println("something else")
}
// and now result equals to Unit-object
```

The same story is with if-else, that is also **expression**.