# Use kotlin enum to avoid else statement in when expressions

Tags: kotlin, enums

I would like to use the `enum` class to create exhaustive lists for `when` statements.

I have created my `enum` class but in `onCreateViewHolder()` I am still getting error message `"A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')"`. The error goes away when i add `else` statement. What's strange is that `onBindViewHolder` works fine even though it implements the same enum elements.

How can I implement the enum here to avoid using `else` block in `onCreateViewHolder()`?

```
    enum class ViewHolderType(val ID: Int) {
        FOOTER(0),
        ITEM(1)
    }
```

```
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == currentList.size) {
            ViewHolderType.FOOTER.ID
        } else {
            ViewHolderType.ITEM.ID
        }
    }
```

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int,
    ): MultiViewViewHolder {

        when (viewType) {
            ViewHolderType.FOOTER.ID -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment_plus_button_new, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder2(view)
            }
            ViewHolderType.ITEM.ID -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder1(view)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MultiViewViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            ViewHolderType.ITEM.ID -> {
                val item = getItem(position)
                holder.onBindViewHolderItem(position, item)
            }
            ViewHolderType.FOOTER.ID -> {
                holder.onBindViewHolderFooter()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can actually lift out return statement like its described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018091/kotlin-return-can-be-lifted-out-of-when

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this so the subject of `when` is an enum rather than an Int:

```
enum class ViewHolderType {
    FOOTER,
    ITEM
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when (position == currentList.size) {
        true -> ViewHolderType.FOOTER
        false -> ViewHolderType.ITEM
    }.ordinal
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int,
): MultiViewViewHolder {

    return when (ViewHolderType.values()[viewType]) {
        ViewHolderType.FOOTER -> {
            val view = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment_plus_button_new, parent, false)
            ViewHolder2(view)
        }
        ViewHolderType.ITEM -> {
            val view = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_fragment, parent, false)
            ViewHolder1(view)
        }
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MultiViewViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (ViewHolderType.values()[getItemViewType(position)]) {
        ViewHolderType.ITEM -> {
            val item = getItem(position)
            holder.onBindViewHolderItem(position, item)
        }
        ViewHolderType.FOOTER -> {
            holder.onBindViewHolderFooter()
        }
    }
}
```

And you don’t need the ID property in your enum class. Often it is recommended not to use the ordinals of enums like this because it prevents changes from being made to the number and order of enum elements without breaking code elsewhere. But this reason doesn’t matter here since it is only used internally to this class, so it’s perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your solution above but get following error at `(viewType)`: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but String was expected`. This corrects if i use `viewType.tostring`, however I am not sure if this is the intended use? Also on your point of not using the `ID` property, when I try to use without `ID` I get an error message on method `getItemViewType()` because ViewHolderType is now returning a 
String and an Int was expected from the method. Would it be possible to provide the full code on how you would implement in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I was answering on my phone and my code was over-simplified. `valueOf` is for the String names, not the indices. You need `values()` and then get the value using array access syntax. The code above is fixed and more thorough.

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. One final question, does it matter what order the elements are listed in the `when` statement? I hope the logic is agnostic to that....

Comment: It's order agnostic since you never are directly using 0 or 1 in your code.